# How do I turn off Notifications that someone "Liked" my comment or reply on Twitter with the new format?

Tags: twitter, notifications

[image]

These are the Notifications options on Twitter now, no option to turn off Likes?

Answer (score 1):

The new Twitter design doesn't have notifications option dedicated just for new likes. The closest you can do is deactivate the **`Updates about the performance of your Tweets`** option. Here is how to do it:

1. Click the **`More`** button at the bottom of the main menu on the left, then click the **`Email notifications`** option (bottom-right)
   [image]
2. Un-check the **`Updates about the performance of your Tweets`** option (middle-right)
   [image]

Alternatively, you can revert back to the old and familiar Twitter design :-) [**here are the instructions**](https://medium.com/@ratson/how-to-switch-back-to-twitters-old-layout-design-9db3e50b151e) how to do it...